# What does "Leidzeit" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I translated "Leidzeit" into English, but I feel somehow it's just a literal translation for this word. I want to know the most usage of this word and how can I use it?

Thanks in advance, my friends.

Comment: Could you please quote the paragraph in which that word appears and give it's source? The context of the word and the time in which the text was written may be relevant for how it can be understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of [*Leidzeit*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/Leidzeit), which can be found in Grimm's dictionary of 1879 but is outdated, the word [*Leidenszeit*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Leidenszeit) is used nowadays.

*Leidenszeit* is a general term that refers to a period of time when someone is suffering. This includes the so-called [*Trauerjahr*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Trauerjahr), i.e., the year of mourning after someone has died, but also periods of suffering from illnes, lovesickness or whatsoever.

Comment: that's good, thanks to teach me similar words. another question here, it can be used as "müde"?

Comment: Moha: no, "müde" is "tired" and not related to mourning at all. IMHO a good translation for "Leid(ens)zeit" would be "time of grief".

Comment: From your dictionary sources alone it seems as if *Leidzeit* ("time of mourning") and *Leidenszeit* ("time of suffering") aren't exactly synonymous and one cannot be used in stead of the other. I would rather say that *Zeit der Trauer* is the contemporary equivalent to *Leidzeit*, not *Leidenszeit*. We don't commonly apply the term *Leidenszeit* to the phase of mourning following a death (although of course it may be a time of suffering for some).

Answer (score 0):

I never heard that word, so I would not assume that there is a meaning or usage. My search engine gives in the first page just hits for "Gleitzeit", so I'm probably not the only one who never heard that word.

I would assume that is is a combination of "Leid" (leiden, suffer) and Zeit (time). Depending on context that can mean almost everything.

An old dictionary indicates that some hundred years ago it might have been used to describe a time of mourning for the loss of relatives.

Comment: I think that's right, it can be used in different situations. maybe it would be better if you provide more examples in your answer.